# Third-party GCM clients for receiving push notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, reverse-engineering, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create a server that generates its own registration ID and uses it to receive GCM notifications. I'm sure it's possible (since Chrome can receive GCM messages—it's just a matter of reverse-engineering the protocol) — are there any libraries out there that implement that?

Comment: There is a library in python for that https://github.com/Francesco149/push_receiver and in js https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/push-receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registration ID is not generated by Chrome, so I don't think you will be able to write a server that would generate Registration IDs that are valid for use with GCM.

The client side request to get a Registration Id is in fact open-sourced and available [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/google_apis/gcm/engine/registration_request.h&q=registration_re&sq=package:chromium&l=1).